# 'AKOscillator' has no member 'rampTime'

Tags: audiokit

I am trying to follow this playgrounds tutorial:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/835-audiokit-tutorial-getting-started

I am trying to follow this part:

```
oscillator.rampTime = 0.2
oscillator.frequency = 500
AKPlaygroundLoop(every: 0.5) {
  oscillator.frequency =
    oscillator.frequency == 500 ? 100 : 500
}
```

But I am getting these errors:

```
error: Oscillators.xcplaygroundpage:13:1: error: value of type 'AKOscillator' has no member 'rampTime'
oscillator.rampTime = 0.2
^~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~

error: Oscillators.xcplaygroundpage:15:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'AKPlaygroundLoop'
AKPlaygroundLoop(every: 0.5) {
```

I have imported the following:

```
import AudioKitPlaygrounds
import AudioKit
import PlaygroundSupport
```

Comment: I noticed the tutorial is a bit outdated and there is rampDuration in the documentation. But I am also unsure about how to use the AKPlaygroundLoop function.

Answer (score 2):

I got rid of the first error by using oscillator.rampDuration instead of rampTime.

For the second error, 'import AudioKitUI' did the job.